# Миксина не видит переменную

Tags: css, sass, scss

Столкнулся с ошибкой: миксина не видит переменную в внешнем окружении, куда была включена.

Пример вставки миксины:

```css
button.endBurger {
    $color: rgba(247, 181, 82, $opacity-bg_conf); // переменная, которую не видит миксина
    background-color: $color;
    width: 250px;
    @include hover-active_add-buts;
}
```

Сама миксина:

```css
@mixin hover-active_add-buts {
    &:hover {
        background: darken($color, $darken-k_add-buts);
    }
    &:active {
        background: darken($color, $darken-k-act_add-buts);
    }
}
```

Код ошибки:

> Error: Undefined variable: "$color"

Comment: Ассоциация - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63795958/mixin-doesnt-see-the-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас переменная `$color` не является глобальной, либо вынесите обьявление переменной за правила селектора `button.endBurger` и других селекторов, чтобы переменная стала глобальной, либо передайте миксину аргумент

```css
@mixin hover-active_add-buts($color) {
    &:hover {
        background: darken($color, $darken-k_add-buts);
    }
    &:active {
        background: darken($color, $darken-k-act_add-buts);
    }
}

button.endBurger {
    $color: rgba(247, 181, 82, $opacity-bg_conf); // переменная, которую не видит миксин
    background-color: $color;
    width: 250px;
    @include hover-active_add-buts($color);
}
```